# To solve "assignment in condition" use of !==false slow down the script. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-studio

I am using zend studio for coding in php.

In `zend studio` the line of `while...` in following code shows `assignment in condition` warning but it work fine and show me tables instantly.

```
$oDB = new db;
print '<strong>Twitter Database Tables</strong><br />';
$result = $oDB->select('SHOW TABLES');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    print $row[0] . '<br />';
}
```

But when I solve this warning with the following code it don't show warning in `zend studio` but it show me tables after long time about `20 to 30 seconds` and long white space under results. Why?

```
$oDB = new db;
print '<strong>Twitter Database Tables</strong><br />';
$result = $oDB->select('SHOW TABLES');
while (( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) !==FALSE) {
    print $row[0] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing that warning in your logs? If you're not, I wouldn't worry about it. You can freely do that assignment in the while with no repercussions, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: It could have something to do with your DB structure. Have you tried a simple query that should be fast to see if it still hangs? Something like: 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1'

Comment: yes it doesn't show any warning in logs. but why it slow down script?

Comment: @Alex only when I add `!==FALSE` then it slow down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php):

> mysqli_fetch_row() returns an array of strings that corresponds to the
>   fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in result set.

You're checking for a BOOL response, so the script continues on. Use either != FALSE or !== NULL.

The code would either be:

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) != FALSE) {
```

OR

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) !== NULL) {
```

Comment: It'll work, and isn't truly wrong. http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php has the comparisons. With ==, NULL will equate to FALSE, but never with === .

Comment: That's right, not _truly_ wrong. It will confuse others into thinking that mysqli_fetch_row returns array or FALSE.

Comment: problem was with `!==FALSE` and use of `!=FALSE or !==Null`  solve the problem